# How to fill area with a vertical line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis, area

I'm trying to make a vertical chart with D3.js and feel the area with a color between the line and the y axis, but it is never filled at all. It only fill a part.

Here an image of the correct chart I'm trying to get:

[image: correct-filled-chart]

Here an image of the wrong chart I have now:

[wrong-filled-chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMBoW.jpg)

With standard chart to fill area is simple. It is possible to use y0 parameter and set it to zero to fill all the area between the x axis and the top values of y in line.

With vertical chart fill area is not so simple for me because I can't use y0 to resolve the problem. The only way for me to have it works is to add at the end of the input array with the lines values, an other element with this values (x,y)=>(0, min-depth). So I have always at least one element with zero for x values.

```js
var allArray = [{
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.02
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.04
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.325,
    "depth": -0.06
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.08
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.1
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.12
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.315,
    "depth": -0.14
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.325,
    "depth": -0.16
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.18
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.2
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.22
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.315,
    "depth": -0.24
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.26
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.28
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.34,
    "depth": -0.3
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.345,
    "depth": -0.32
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.355,
    "depth": -0.34
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.37,
    "depth": -0.36
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.365,
    "depth": -0.38
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.4
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.42
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.3,
    "depth": -0.44
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.29,
    "depth": -0.46
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.235,
    "depth": -0.48
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.22,
    "depth": -0.5
  }
];

draw2("#svg4a", allArray);

function draw2(selector2, allArray) {

  var data = allArray;

  var startElement = { depth: 0, parameter: 0.3 };

  data.unshift(startElement);

  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 35
  };
  var width = 150 - margin.left,
    height = 580 - margin.top;

  var svg = d3.select(selector2)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "SVGcontent")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top);

  // Pattern definition
  const defs = svg.append('defs')
    .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'whitecarbon2')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 4)
    .attr('height', 4)
    .append('path')
    .attr('stroke', '#010101')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2');

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.parameter = parseFloat(d.parameter);
  });
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
      d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.parameter
      }) + 0.4, 0
    ])
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
      0,
      d3.min(data, function(d) {
        return d.depth
      })
    ])
    .range([0, height - 20]);

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.parameter)
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.depth)
    });

  var artboard = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(35," + margin.top + ")");

  var area = d3.area()
  .x1(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.parameter)
  })
  .x0(xScale(0))
  .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.depth)
  });

  // add the area
  artboard.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "areaColore1")
    .attr("d", area)
    .attr("fill", "#fefefe");

  // add the pattern
  artboard.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style('stroke', '#777777')
    .attr("fill", "url(#whitecarbon2)");

  artboard.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("fill", "none");

  var xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale);

  ticks = xScale.ticks(1);
  ticks.push(0);
  ticks.push(0.3);
  xAxis.tickValues(ticks);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", -15)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(none)")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .attr("class", "yAxis")
    .call(yAxis);
  // Adding title label to axis Y
  artboard.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("x", 6)
    // .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style('fill', '#777777')
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text("Depth [m]");


  function make_x_gridlines() {
    return xAxis.ticks(1);
  }

  function make_y_gridlines() {
    return yAxis.ticks(11);
  }


  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid gridX")
    .call(make_x_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-height + margin.top - 50)
      .tickFormat("")
    )

  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid gridY2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(make_y_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-200)
      .tickFormat("")
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg4a"></div>
```

Expected: filled with color all the area from vertical values line to y axis.

Actual: filled area only for the joining line between the first and the last point values of the line.

Here a live example:   [Live chart](http://tpcg.io/S43Yvf)

**NB:**
I also tried to added this code to make always 0 in parameter field, so the chart was filled correctly.

The code I added was this one:

```
  var startElement = { depth: 0, parameter: 0.3 };

  data.unshift(startElement);
```

and this one works fine also without to set .x0 (even if it is correct to set it). 
But my target was to find a configuration where I don't have to be obligated to insert a fake value in the input array values. I think that insert .x0 should be enough to make the chart fill in the whole, like y0 make fill from zero to parameters values if chart is in horizontal mode.
There is a way to do it without insert a fake value?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vertical area chart you should not use `x`, `y0` and `y1`. You should use `y`, `x0` and `x1` instead:

```
var area = d3.area()
    .x1(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.parameter)
    })
    .x0(xScale(0))
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.depth)
    });
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var allArray = [{
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": 0
  }, {
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.02
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.04
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.325,
    "depth": -0.06
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.08
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.1
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.12
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.315,
    "depth": -0.14
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.325,
    "depth": -0.16
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.18
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.2
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.22
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.315,
    "depth": -0.24
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.26
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.33,
    "depth": -0.28
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.34,
    "depth": -0.3
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.345,
    "depth": -0.32
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.355,
    "depth": -0.34
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.37,
    "depth": -0.36
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.365,
    "depth": -0.38
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.335,
    "depth": -0.4
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.32,
    "depth": -0.42
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.3,
    "depth": -0.44
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.29,
    "depth": -0.46
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.235,
    "depth": -0.48
  },
  {
    "parameter": 0.22,
    "depth": -0.5
  }
];

draw2("#svg4a", allArray);

function draw2(selector2, allArray) {

  var data = allArray;

  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 35
  };
  var width = 150 - margin.left,
    height = 580 - margin.top;

  var svg = d3.select(selector2)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "SVGcontent")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top);

  // Pattern definition
  const defs = svg.append('defs')
    .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'whitecarbon2')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 4)
    .attr('height', 4)
    .append('path')
    .attr('stroke', '#010101')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2');

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.parameter = parseFloat(d.parameter);
  });
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
      d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.parameter
      }) + 0.4, 0
    ])
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
      0,
      d3.min(data, function(d) {
        return d.depth
      })
    ])
    .range([0, height - 20]);

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.parameter)
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.depth)
    });

  var artboard = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(35," + margin.top + ")");

  var area = d3.area()
    .x1(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.parameter)
    })
    .x0(xScale(0))
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.depth)
    });

  // add the area
  artboard.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "areaColore1")
    .attr("d", area)
    .attr("fill", "#fefefe");

  // add the pattern
  artboard.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style('stroke', '#777777')
    .attr("fill", "url(#whitecarbon2)");

  artboard.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("fill", "none");

  var xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale);

  ticks = xScale.ticks(1);
  ticks.push(0);
  ticks.push(0.3);
  xAxis.tickValues(ticks);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", -15)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(none)")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .attr("class", "yAxis")
    .call(yAxis);
  // Adding title label to axis Y
  artboard.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("x", 6)
    // .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style('fill', '#777777')
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text("Depth [m]");


  function make_x_gridlines() {
    return xAxis.ticks(1);
  }

  function make_y_gridlines() {
    return yAxis.ticks(11);
  }


  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid gridX")
    .call(make_x_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-height + margin.top - 50)
      .tickFormat("")
    )

  artboard.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid gridY2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(make_y_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-200)
      .tickFormat("")
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg4a"></div>
```

---

PS: For having an area chart just like the one in your image you need the first data point having 0 depth.

Comment: I added a point at the end of my first post. Thanks for the reply! I'd like to have a configuration value to make always the chart filled from zero, as it happens for horizontal charts when I set y0 value. I've been asked myself why with .x0 it's not possible to do it but I have to add a fake value to make it possible .. Thanks!